# Limit specific part of active record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im having difficulty figuring out how to limit the correct part of my query results. Basically I am attempting to get all users that fit a criteria as well as the current user.

My code for this is:

```
@users = users.where(id: current_user).or(users.where('email LIKE ?', "%#{user_email}%")).limit(10)
```

The issue arises because the current user may not be in the ten listed if there are too many matching users.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
@users = users.
          where(id: current_user).
          or(users.where('email LIKE ?', "%#{user_email}%")).
          order(Arel.sql("case when talents.id = #{current_user} then 1 else 2 end")).
          limit(10)
```

With this order by clause you made a row that match id show a first row of result

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!